# substring MADNESS simple but it isn't working?

Tags: java

```
 public class Tester{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "any";
        System.out.println (a.substring (0,2));
    }
}
```

Why does this output "an" instead of "any"?

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)). "_substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) - Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex._"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the second argument for substring is exclusive - up and until 2, not including.

This is all explained by the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) for the `substring` method.

Here are the indicies - remember they start at 0.

> any 
>   | |  | 
>   012

So [0,2) gives 0 and 1 - "an"

If you want the "y" to be included, just add one, so you'd have `"any".substring(0,3)`;

Comment: I can't yet, give me 3 more minutes. Also, in your response, you can put [0,2)? I thought it was (0,2)

Comment: @learningcomputerguy The "[" symbol means inclusive in math terms, and the "(" symbol means exclusive in math terms. You can't use them for programming. It is just a way of notating inclusive and exclusive.

Comment: alright, at least you get rep for giving advice to noobs, gratz, have a nice night

Comment: @learningcomputerguy you too. Consider googling this sort of thing next time. Just enter something like "substring java" - one of the top hits will be documentation, and it should be very helpful next time.

Answer (score 1):

The end index of `substring` (i.e. the second argument) is exclusive. Therefore, the character at index 2 (y) will not be included any more.